# App Crash :ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE issue with modifiers in android studio java class

Tags: java, android, global-variables, crash-reports

**hello everyone**
i am new in android development and i have a code that use simple `intent` to take photo .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ImageView mImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_taken_picture);
 static final int request=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

public void takePicture(View view )
{
    Intent i_picture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(i_picture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    {
        startActivityForResult(i_picture,request);
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent dat) {

    if(requestCode==request && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle extra = dat.getExtras();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)extra.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    }
}
```

}

but i always get **Unfortunately,App has stopped**
i know the problem is with the *java class* more specifically the first two  **Variables ImageView and int**
any help !
and thanks in advance ...

Comment: Add logcats. Debugging a crash without logs is needlessly hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ImageView` initialization  line is a crash first, you can't initialize your view before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` because before this line `activity` don't even know about any `XML` attached to it so activity will say "hey i don't have anything like R.id.image_view_taken_picture 'cuz i don't have any XML layout"

```
ImageView mImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_taken_picture); // crash
```

do the initialization in `onCreate` after `setContentView`

```
ImageView mImageView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_taken_picture);
    }
```

Second you don't have to pass the view to `takePicture` function

```
public void takePicture()
{
    Intent i_picture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(i_picture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    {
        startActivityForResult(i_picture,request);
    }

}
```

now just call it like this `takePicture()` whenever you want to take a pic

Comment: @Pavrieet Singh . thank you for this answer . its worked and the explanation was totally fabulous . :)

Comment: my pleasure ,i am glad you liked it and thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: you worth all what i said :) .
i have one more question , would you like to help me with ?

Comment: if it is something which can be answered without looking any code then why not ?

Comment: you know that if we want to save pic in storage phone we use "file"  but i didn`t used it and my pic exist in the storage of the phone .i i used the same code above .

Comment: the pic need to be stored somewhere so either you can give your specific location to store pic by passing uri to camera intent or it will be stored in some public folder used by camera app.

Comment: so, you mean that the taken pic will always be stored in the storage even if i didn`t uses the " file " class ?

Comment: yup, pic is like a file so it will take storage and it's not a temporary file which will go away automatically although you can delete it but for that you need `WRITE_PERMISSION`

Comment: my pleasure and just keep in mind you can't delete files from external sdcard on kitkat and above.but you can delete pic because it will be stored in phone storage